# Algoritmo para convertir una lista de nodos en una matriz

Tags: c#, lista, algoritmos, matriz, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo un grafo almacenado en forma de lista de nodos y necesito crear un algoritmo que convierta la lista en un array bidimensional que represente los nodos respetando las conexiones entre ellos. Yo lo estoy haciendo en C# pero debido a que es un problema conceptual no importa el lenguaje de programación.

Un nodo no es más que esto:

```
public class Node
{
    public string id;
    public List<Node> connections;
}
```

Cada nodo esta compuesto por un identificador y una lista.
La lista incluye referencias a otros nodos con los que se conecta.

**Características de la lista:**

1. Un nodo nunca estará incluido dentro de su propia lista.
2. En la lista no habrá nodos repetidos.
3. Puede haber entre 1 y 4 nodos en la lista.

**Ejemplo**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No queda del todo claro cómo sería la representación en forma de matriz, en particular cómo almacena la matriz las conexiones entre nodos. No es por simple adyacencia, pues por ejemplo B y F en la primera matriz son adyacentes, pero no están conectados.

Comment: Es muy simple. Incluso para grafos dirigidos y/o ponderados. 1. asignar a cada nodo un identificador numérico de 1 a n. 2. Crear una matriz cuadrada de orden n  (n x n) 3. a los elementos de la matriz A(i,j) se les asigna 1 o 0 si hay un segmento que conecte a i, j. Si el grafo es ponderado asignas el peso o 0 si no es dirigido y A(i,j) != 0 entonces A(j,i) != 0 si es dirigido 1, 0 o peso en cada dirección. Etc Lee Graph Theory de Narshing Deo

Comment: Ejemplo para primer nodo fila A: En tu caso asignemos A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc. tendríamos M[1][3] = 1,  M[1][4] = 1,  M[1][6] = 1 y los demás elementos de esa línea =s a 0, **Nota** estoy usando base 1 para los vectores fila y columna, se puede igual hacer con base 0.

Comment: Lo siento, me esta costando trabajo entenderlo. Ahora mismo tengo asignado un número a cada nodo y he creado una matriz de 7 x 7. Luego he colocado un 1 siguiendo el procedimiento que me has comentado. Pero creo que lo tengo mal. ¿Ahora que hago con esto? (las casillas vacías son 0) Comparto una imagen hecha en paint rápidamente: https://imgur.com/w4B2lg1

Comment: Una duda, las características de la lista están, resueltas, si es así se te podría dar una respuesta asumiendo que ya tu validas estas características cuando creas el grafo

Comment: El grafo lo crea el usuario en una aplicación gráfica y voy guardando los nodos en una lista. Luego solo tengo que hacer uso de los métodos "Contains" y "Count" para sacar la información que menciono en el enunciado. Estos métodos son propios de las listas en C#, no he realizado ningún procedimiento lógico complejo para obtener esos datos.

Comment: Os muestro una imagen del grafo: https://imgur.com/P2HH6F7 Esa es la única información de la que dispongo. Una lista con todos los nodos y sus conexiones. Pero tengo que convertir la lista en una matriz y no se me ocurre como. Los elementos no tienen por que estar colocados de la misma forma que en el grafo. Lo importante es que si un nodo esta conectado a otro, esos dos estén al lado el uno del otro en la matriz. Las matrices de la imagen del enunciado son correctas porque respetan las conexiones, aunque haya nodos juntos y que no estén conectados como indica "abulafia".

Comment: A ver pq me parece que no entendiste,  en tu enunciado mencionas que se tienen que cumplir 3 características, la pregunta mía es,  para poderte ayudar asumimos, que ya esas características se cumplen, ya tu te encargaste de eso

Comment: Otra duda tu estructura de datos la organízate como una lista de nodos donde cada nodo tiene otra lista de nodos

Comment: Efectivamente, hay una lista principal que contiene todos los nodos del grafo. Y cada nodo no es más que otra lista de nodos y un string. Y garantizo que las 3 características del enunciado ya se cumplen. El algoritmo que busco no tiene que lidiar con eso, esa parte esta resuelta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con las respuestas que has recibido hasta ahora es que lo que te dan como resultado es una matriz de adyacencia, que no es lo que necesitas.

En la matriz de adyacencia las "coordenadas" de un punto de la matriz (fila y columna) representan nodos del grafo ("A", "B", etc.) y el contenido de ese elemento de la matriz representa si hay unión o no entre los dos nodos. Así, si en la fila "A" columna "B" hay un 1, es que "A" y "B" están unidos y si hay un 0 es que no. Es otra forma de representar el grafo, alternativa a tu lista de nodos y listas. Pero no es un "gráfico" del grafo. No coloca adyacentes los nodos que estén unidos, que es lo que necesitas.

Por otro lado, la representación en forma de matriz que pides, es ambigua. Si el resultado fuese:

```
A B
C D
```

¿cómo sabrías cuáles están conectados con cuáles? Sólo por estar unos al lado de otros no tienes esa información. Esta matriz podría representar tanto al grafo `A->B->D->C`, como al `A->C->D->B` como a `B->A->C->D`, etc..

De todas formas asumiendo que realmente es esta salida (ambigua) la que necesitas, se me ha ocurrido un algoritmo para obtener lo que pides, pero lo he implementado en Python porque requiere mucho menos código (y porque el C# no es lo mío). La implementación python puede servir para demostrar mediante ejemplos que el algoritmo funciona. Si sabes python te puede servir de inspiración para "traducirlo" a C#. Pero aún si no sabes python, trataré de describir el algoritmo con palabras y pseudocódigo para que te sea más sencillo de entender y adaptar.

### El algoritmo

La idea parte de preparar una matriz de tamaño suficiente como para albergar el gráfico que queremos como resultado, buscar el nodo del grafo que más vecinos tiene (el máximo es 4) y colocar ese nodo en el centro de la matriz, para después ir pintando sus vecinos mediante llamadas recursivas (que a su vez pintarán a sus vecinos, etc.)

De entrada, no sabemos qué tamaño necesitaremos para esa matriz, de modo que para ir por la vía fácil, le doy tamaño "abundante". En concreto crearé una matriz cuadrada que tenga como número de filas y de columnas el doble del número de nodos en tu grafo. De este modo, incluso el "caso peor" cabe. Ese caso peor consiste en una "cadena de nodos", que comenzaría en el centro y llegaría linealmente hasta un borde.

Más adelante me ocuparé de, una vez creado "el gráfico" (es decir, rellena esa matriz), recortarla para eliminar las filas y columnas que hayan quedado vacías.

Así pues, el pseudocódigo de la solución general sería:

```
Averiguar el número total de nodos a representar --> N
Averiguar el "nombre" del nodo que tiene más vecinos --> inicio
Crear un grid de 2Nx2N y rellenarlo con un cierto carácter de relleno
Llamar a una función colocar_vecinos(inicio, N, N)
  (esta función modifica el grid recursivamente hasta haber colocado a todos)
Recortar el grid para eliminar filas y columnas que contengan solo relleno
```

Como ves, la clave ahora es la función recursiva que coloca los nodos. Funcionaría en la forma siguiente:

```
funcion colocar_vecinos(nodo, x, y)
   Si el nodo no está en el grafo, retornar
   Obtener la lista de vecinos del nodo
   Colocar el nodo en grid[x,y]
   Eliminar el nodo del grafo
   Para cada vecino:
      calcular coordenadas x, y, donde poner al vecino
      colocar_vecinos(vecino, x, y)
```

Vemos que esa función modifica el grafo, pues va eliminando a los nodos que ya ha colocado (para evitar que intenten ser colocados de nuevo cuando vuelven a aparecer como vecinos de otros). Ya que esto destruye el grafo original será conveniente sacar una copia del grafo antes de llamar a esta función.

Las coordenadas donde colocar cada vecino serían simplemente `(x-1,y)`, `(x,y+1)`, `(x+1,y)` y `(x,y-1)`, según se va iterando por la lista de vecinos.

### Implementación

Todo lo anterior se implementa en el siguiente código Python, que espera que el grafo le sea dado como un diccionario en el que las claves son los "nombres" de los nodos, y los valores son las listas de vecinos. Por ejemplo, el grafo que das como ejemplo en la pregunta sería representado por:

```py
grafo = {
    "A": ["C", "D", "F"],
    "B": ["C", "E"],
    "C": ["A", "B"],
    "D": ["A", "G"],
    "E": ["B"],
    "F": ["A"],
    "G": ["D"]
}
```

Primero algunas funciones auxilares:

```py
def print_grid(grid):
  "Imprime el grid"
  for line in grid:
    print(" ".join(line))

def recortar_grid(grid):
  "Elimina los bordes vacíos del grid, dejando solo la región con nodos"

  # Elminar filas "vacías" (que contengan solo el punto)
  ok = [ line for line in grid if not set(line)==set(["."]) ]
  # Transponer el grid
  ok = list(map(list, zip(*ok)))
  # Eliminar otra vez filas vacías tras la transposición
  ok = [ line for line in ok if not set(line)==set(["."]) ]
  # Transponer otra vez para devolver resultado
  ok = list(map(list, zip(*ok)))
  return list(ok)
```

Ahora la implementación de la función recursiva que es el núcleo del algoritmo. En la implementación Python recibe el grid como parámetro y actúa directamente sobre él. Podría haber sido también una variable global.

```py
def coloca_vecinos(grid, node, x, y):
  "Coloca el nodo en la posición dada del grid, y recursivamente a sus vecinos"
  if node not in grafo:
    return

  # Chequeo frente a bugs, esto no debería ocurrir (intentar poner un nodo ya puesto)
  if grid[y][x] != "." and grid[y][x] != node:
    raise Exception(f"Colisión, intento de poner '{node}' en ({x},{y}) donde ya estaba {grid[y][x]}'")

  # Obtener la lista de vecinos y eliminar el nodo del grafo
  vecinos = grafo.get(node, [])
  del grafo[node]

  # Poner al nodo en el grid, y a su lista de vecinos alrededor, recursivamente
  grid[y][x] = node
  for vecino, (deltax, deltay) in zip(vecinos, ((-1,0), (0,1), (1,0), (0,-1))):
    coloca_vecinos(grid, vecino, x+deltax, y+deltay)
```

Y la función principal que maneja todo lo anterior:

```py
def grafo_to_grid(grafo):
  # Sacar copia, porque el grafo será destruido en el proceso
  grafo = grafo.copy()
  
  # Encontrar el nodo con mayor número de vecinos
  inicio = max(grafo, key=lambda x: len(grafo[x]))

  # Crear grid de tamaño suficiente
  grid = [ [ "." for _ in range(2*len(grafo))] for _ in range(2*len(grafo)) ]
  centro = len(grafo)

  # Poner en el centro el nodo elegido, y recursivamente todos los demás alrededor
  coloca_vecinos(grid, inicio, centro, centro)

  # Eliminar lo que sobra del grid
  grid = recortar_grid(grid)

  # Mostrarlo (o retornarlo, como prefieras)
  print_grid(grid)
  # return grid
```

### Ejemplos

Finalmente, un par de ejecuciones de ejemplo:

```py
grafo = {
    "A": ["C", "D", "F"],
    "B": ["C", "E"],
    "C": ["A", "B"],
    "D": ["A", "G"],
    "E": ["B"],
    "F": ["A"],
    "G": ["D"]
}
grafo_to_grid(grafo)
```

Sale

```
C A F
B D .
E G .
```

Realmemente, como decía al principio, es imposible "ver" en esta salida qué estructura tenía el grafo, pero puedes verificar que se cumple que los nodos que en el grafo de entrada estaban conectados, en el grid resultado aparecen adyacentes.

Otro ejemplo (basado en otra de las imágenes que suministras):

```py
grafo = {
    "⭐": [""],
    "": ["⭐", "⚔️", ""],
    "⚔️": ["", "❌"],
    "": ["❌", ""],
    "❌": ["", ""],
    "": ["❌", "⛳"]
}
grafo_to_grid(grafo)
```

Resultado:

```
⭐ 
. ⚔️
 ❌
.
```

Un par de notas sobre este último:

- Quise hacer algo llamativo y usé emojis como "nombres" de los nodos, pero debido a que algunos emojis tienen ancho doble que otros, la matriz resultante no quedó bien alineada.
- El algoritmo no permite que haya dos nodos con el mismo "nombre", por eso he tenido que cambiar una de las "espadas cruzadas" por el aspa roja.

Comment: No he terminado de leer toda la solución pero quería felicitarte de antemano. Solo he leído la introducción y un poco del apartado "algoritmo". Pero el procedimiento lógico que has seguido coincide con el que yo he tenido cuando estaba solo (lo de dar un tamaño grande a la matriz, colocar el nodo más conectado primero, etc) y eso me inspira mucha confianza. Además veo que has explicado todo con mucho detalle, gracias. Voy a terminar de leer, implementar y te digo si me ha servido. Si tengo alguna duda te la comento.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona bien. En realidad ya tenía resuelto el problema pero tenía que optimizarlo porque algunos grafos los hacía extremadamente lentos. Hemos seguido el mismo procedimiento para resolverlo solo que tu usas recursividad en la función para colocar los nodos y yo recorría la matriz para encontrar el punto con menor entropía como se explica en este artículo: https://robertheaton.com/2018/12/17/wavefunction-collapse-algorithm/ Creo que por eso me iba tan lento. Gracias por ayudarme ❤️

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> nombreNodos = new List<string>(){"A","B","C","D"};// Pones tantas letras como te hagan falta
int dimension = listaNodos.Count();
int[,] matriz = new int[dimension, dimension];
idNodo=0;
idCon=0;

foreach(var n in listaNodos)
{
   idNodo = nombreNodos.indexOf(n.id);

   foreach(var c in n.connections)
   {
     idCon = nombreNodos.indexOf(c.id);
      matriz[idNodo,idCon] = 1;
   }
}
```

Hay varias formas de tratar los grafos una es mediante una matriz de adyacencia y otra es mediante una matriz de incidencia, aquí te explico con la matriz de adyacencia. Una matriz de adyacencia pone 1 en la intersección de la fila y la columna que indican que ese nodo tiene conexión con otro nodo, Ej si el nodo A tiene un enlace con el nodo B pues la celda de la matriz que representa esa conexión de nodos toma el valor 1, de no existir conexión entre esos nodos el valor será 0.
Ahora bien, lo q se hace aquí es crear una lista que tiene los nombres de los nodos, representado con las letras del alfabeto.
Hacemos un ciclo que recorra cada nodo de la lista de nodos y dentro de este ciclo hacemos otro que recorra todas las conexiones de este nodo, posteriormente guardamos los id de los nodos y buscamos que posición tienen estos id en la lista de los nombres, esta posición es la que nos indicará cuál es la celda que se pondrá en 1

Comment: Mira a ver, cualquier duda me escibes

Comment: He implementado tu código pero no es el resultado que necesito. No soy ingeniero informático ni matemático así que no sabía que era una matriz de adyacencia, pero he investigado un poco y estoy seguro de que no es lo que estoy buscando (a no ser que me ayude a conseguir el resultado final). Creo que no he expuesto bien el enunciado y por eso no se ha entendido. Por favor, mirad la siguiente imágen, espero que sea más claro: https://imgur.com/E6YSlb5 Arriba a la derecha se ver la matriz resultante de aplicar tu lógica, las otras tres matrices de la izquierda es lo que estoy buscando conseguir.